# Output of arbiter not stable

Tags: chisel

I have just found out this problem.

Suppose I use a Arbiter to arbitrate the output of a bus driver from multiple parallel transaction initiators. The bus and initiators use DecoupledIO. It is known that Arbiter prioritizes in(0) over in(1). Considering this case:

```
clock 1: in(0).valid = 0, in(1).valid = 1  -> out === in(1) out.valid = 1  out.ready = 0
clock 2: in(1).valid = 1, in(1).valid = 1  -> out === in(0) out.valid = 1  out.ready = 1
```

So both clock 1 and 2 have bus.valid === 1
If a client on this bus cannot response in the same cycle but the next cycle,
the out.ready driven by this client is actually corresponding to in(1) NOT in(0) in clock 2.

I would expect the arbiter to choose in(0) if in(0) and in(1) become valid at the same clock cycle, but if in(1) turns valid before in(0), the arbiter keeps selecting in(1) until in(1) is fired.

In this case, LockingArbiter, RRArbiter all have the same behaviour, that higher priority input can always preempt lower priority input before the lower input is locked (when count == 1, there is no lock at all).

I am kind of seeing this non-stable output as a bug-like issue of Arbiter.
Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You can use a LockingArbiter with a needsLock argument. Arbiter is actually a subclass of LockingArbiter with needsLock set to None and count=1.

Comment: Reading your question again made me realize that I didn't fully understand the question in the first place! Why do you expect "the arbiter to keep selecting in(1)"?  in(0) has a higher priority and it needs to be served whenever it goes valid. That's what I thought a priority arbiter should behave like anyways. Maybe you actually need RR arbitration (Chisel.RRArbiter)?

Comment: If you see the definition of Arbiter, it is already LockingArbiter(gen, n, 1, None). RRArbiter does not help as well. Arbiter give in(0) the highest priority, RRArbiter give the input next to the last locked input the highest priority. So if when a lower priority input is valid before the highest one, the highest one can always preempt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "needsHold" parameter is added to all arbiters to enable this hold requirement. This feature is disabled by default. This is included in Chisel by commit 18ecaf8de4a5.